# How to get the number of row where I could find a specific value in RobotFramework?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, selenium2library

I already written something like that:

```
Check privileges for PDTA
    ${end}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    //*[@id="listForm:displayDataTable:tbody"]/tr
    ${start}=    Set Variable    0
    : FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    ${start}    ${end}
    \    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Element Should Contain    listForm:displayDataTable:${index}    su    ${index}
```

And the log output is:

[image: output.html]

As you can see I want to get the number of row where I could find the value 'su'. This value can be found in a row number 6. Variable ${end} equals the number of all rows in the table.

Does anyone know how to get that number? Maybe there's a keyword which could help me, isn't it? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: you want to output the row number where you've found 'su' ?  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the row number where I've found 'su'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
: FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    ${start}    ${end}
\    ${Name}=    Get Text    listForm:displayDataTable:${index}
\    ${IsEqual}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Be Equal    ${Name}    Su
\    ${RowNumber}=    Set Variable    ${index}
\    Run Keyword If    '${IsEqual}'=='True'    Run Keywords    Log    Rownumber is ${RowNumber}    AND    Exit For Loop
```

U can try this.

The variable  *${RowNumber}* gets the row number which has the text "Su".

Comment: Will it only ever be one row?  The above will cause problems if you're expecting multiples.  But to deal with that just remove the exit of the for loop

Comment: Yes, it will always be one row. It is a unique value. I needed that row number to click a specific button. Ok, thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0):

As part of your FOR loop, I would add:

```
Run Keyword If    '${status}' == 'PASS'    Log    ${index}
```

If you need to actually use it then simply set a variable or append to a list variable or something